Tactic proof of even induction
How do you prove even induction with just tactics?
Basically, even induction seems to be easiest to prove by just writing out a Function or Program or whatever, I'm wondering if you can prove it without doing that.

I am messing around with this question and trying to prove some random lemmas about even numbers.
Eventually, I had the idea to write an even induction theorem.
Fixpoint even_induction_func (f : nat -> Type) (case0 : f 0) (case1 : f 1) (i : forall x, f x -> f (S (S x))) y := 
  match y with                                                                                                 
  | O => case0                                                                                                 
  | S O => case1                                                                                               
  | S (S w) => (i w) (even_induction_func f case0 case1 i w) 
  end 
. 
 
Theorem even_induction : forall f, f 0 -> f 1 -> (forall x, f x -> f (S (S x))) -> (forall y, f y). 
Proof. 
  intros f case0 case1 i y.                                                                                    
  pose proof even_induction_func f case0 case1 i y.                                                            
  intuition. 
Qed.

As a quick aside, I'm pretty sure that I can just use the function definition of even_induction_func as my even induction principle, but it is printed as
fix even_induction_func
  (f : nat -> Type) (case0 : f 0) (case1 : f 1)
  (i : forall x : nat, f x -> f (S (S x))) (y : nat) {struct y} : f y.

I don't know what {struct y} means, so I am using a perhaps-unnecessary Theorem so I get better control over the type.
This is actually not the first thing I tried for even induction, I tried just inducting twice.
Theorem even_induction_tactical : forall f, f 0 -> f 1 -> (forall x, f x -> f (S (S x))) -> (forall y, f y).   
Proof. 
  intro f.                                                                                                     
  intro H0.                                                                                                    
  intro H1.                                                                                                    
  intro IH.                                                                                                    
  intro y. 
  induction y.                                                                                                 
  - intuition.                                                                                                 
  - induction y.                                                                                               
    + intuition.                                                                                               
    + firstorder.                                                                                              
Abort.

However, I ended up with this environment and no idea how to make progress. I strongly suspect that there is no way to make progress because even induction, in real life, really is quite different from ordinary induction.
  f : nat -> Type
  H0 : f 0
  H1 : f 1
  IH : forall x : nat, f x -> f (S (S x))
  y : nat
  IHy : f (S y)
  IHy0 : f y -> f (S y)
  ============================
  f (S (S y))


You'd use strong induction, which can be derived from regular induction. Alternatively, you can use the fix tactic to build a fixpoint in your tactic proof. But I am not sure this is what you are asking about.

Also note that the {struct y} is not really part of the type, it only tells you that the fixed point is defined by guarded recursion on y. There's no need to "get rid of it," nor is that possible in general, as you can only hide it.

Solution 1: prove forall x, (f x)*(f (S x)) by normal induction and use that to get forall x, f x:
Theorem even_induction :
  forall f, f 0 -> f 1 -> (forall x, f x -> f (S (S x))) -> (forall x, f x).
Proof.
  intros f case0 case1 IH_even.
  assert (lemma : forall x, (f x)*(f (S x))). {
    induction x as [|x IH_normal].
    - split.
      + exact case0.
      + exact case1.
    - destruct IH_normal as [fx fSx]. split.
      + exact fSx.
      + apply IH_even. exact fx.
  }
  intros x. destruct (lemma x) as [fx fSx]. exact fx.
Qed.

Solution 2: build the fixpoint explicitly in the proof, using refine:
Theorem even_induction :
  forall f, f 0 -> f 1 -> (forall x, f x -> f (S (S x))) -> (forall x, f x).
Proof.
  intros f case0 case1 IH_even.
  refine (fix rec x := _).
  destruct x.
  - exact case0.
  - destruct x.
    + exact case1.
    + apply IH_even. apply rec.
Qed.

Solution 3: use strong induction, which exists in the standard library under the more general form of well-founded induction:
Require Import PeanoNat.

Theorem even_induction :
  forall f, f 0 -> f 1 -> (forall x, f x -> f (S (S x))) -> (forall x, f x).
Proof.
  intros f case0 case1 IH_even.
  induction x as [x IH_strong] using (well_founded_induction_type Nat.lt_wf_0).
  destruct x.
  - exact case0.
  - destruct x.
    + exact case1.
    + apply IH_even. apply IH_strong.
      transitivity (S x); apply Nat.lt_succ_diag_r.
Qed.

